# Setting Content-Type key when uploading directory using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using os.walk to get a directory of files and then using the boto suggested way of uploading large files.  From what I have read, I need to set the content-type key at upload time, but the directory has multiple file types that need different content-type keys.  Any suggestions on how to get the proper content-type for each file so it can be set in the key?  Mime types library?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-data):

> When you send data to S3 from a file or filename, boto will attempt to determine the correct mime type for that file and send it as a Content-Type header. The boto package uses the standard mimetypes package in Python to do the mime type guessing.

From the [source](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/key.py#L920):

```
self.content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(self.path)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, for the link.  But I am not finding this to be the case.  Example, when I upload a .jpg using boto, it sets the content-type as binary/octet-stream.  If I upload the file in the s3 interface, or use transmit to send the same file, they both set the correct content type.

Comment: Yes, the code would be most helpful.  Also, if for some reason boto is not guessing the mime type correctly, you can always set the mime type explicitly by setting the ``content_type`` attribute of the ``Key`` object.